# Arithmetic operations using list

Tags: python, list, matlab

I am trying to write a `MATLAB` code into `python`. The original `MATLAB` code is from this following vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T97ddyTMuro. Briefly, the `MATLAB` code is as follows:

```
v = 10;
theta = linspace(15, 75, 100);
g = 9.81;
t = 2*v*sin(theta)/g;
r = v*cos(theta).*t;
plot(r,theta)
```

I was trying to recreate this code in `python`, attached herewith is what I have tried and failed:

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
theta = np.linspace(0,70,100)
v = 10 # velocity (m/s)
g = 9.81 # accel. due to grav.
t = []
r = []
a = []
multi =[]
for i in np.linspace(0,70,100):
    t.append(2*v*(m.sin(np.deg2rad(i)))/g)
    for j in np.linspace(0,70,100):
        r.append(v*(m.cos(np.deg2rad(i))))
        a.append(r[j]*t[j])
```

Unable to multiply two `lists` as they are not integers.

Comment: Use `np.dot` for vector/matrix multiplication

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach is to directly use only `numpy` code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
theta = np.deg2rad(np.linspace(0,70,100))
v = 10 # velocity (m/s)
g = 9.81 # accel. due to grav.

t1 = 2*v*np.sin(theta)/g
r = v*np.cos(theta)*t1  # will compute elementwise multiplication

plt.plot(r, theta)
plt.show()
```